# Rails register User using phone number and confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sms

I am building an iPhone app and the rails backend for it. I want the user to register via their phone number and a confirmation code sent using SMS. It should work like WhatsApps authentication.

Does anyone know a gem, ideally for devise, or do I have to build this on my own?

Comment: you obviously will use side-service to send SMS, some of them provide gems, look at heroku addons if you want to deploy on heroku

Comment: Yes, that was clear to me too. Thanks, i will have  loko at herokus add ons.

Comment: This is a very broad question and it is unlikely anyone will give you "do this and that" answer. First as Joe suggested look for sms service (this wil take you a while ;). For confirmation I think you may use slightly altered Confirmable module, wiki pages covering other common features may be a help here.

Comment: Also stumbled upon this https://github.com/baranov-sv/devise_sms_confirmable but readme is entirely in Russian and seems to support only some Russian sms-service but still may be some help

Comment: There are heroku sms addons which provide gem for Rails...but they won't deal confirmation by themself, they will just send that you pass as argument. So generation of SMS code is your work. As code from SMS can't be such long and complicated as URL confimation, which user simply follow from mail, there are subtle things...read some articles on these topic