# Rails - Validate User by Text Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Just wanted to see if anyone was aware of a gem that exists to validate an account via a text message/code.  I think this would help provide a little more evidence that users are not robots and better validate an account.  I have spent some time searching but may not have the best search terms on this being pretty new to rails.

Comment: There are wonderful methods to rule out bots, even without using charged services. Why not use a captcha, or an email verification????

Comment: Those work and I have used them in the past for other types of websites but for this kind of website I want to ensure greater security against robots.  If I can require an omniauth-facebook sign in with a verified phone number I think that would go much further towards validating a human and ensuring that my customers are only interacting with real people.

Comment: Also, not sure this would need to be a charged service.  If you know a phone number and a provider, you can email a code to that phone number and it will be received via SMS.  I could build this external to the app and manually approve accounts (or have someone do this) but just wanted to see if something already existed before planning that route.

Comment: Ok, those are good reasons. Maybe you should put some writing into your question, providing more details of your work so far to make it more appealing to collaborators. Those two comments you wrote do explain a little more of your plans.

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521712/phone-number-based-devise-authentication-for-mobile-apps but it's close.  You might find something useful there.

Comment: What you're asking for is not validation - it's confirmation. If I had to build something like this is would have Rails send a confirmation key via a SMS service like [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms), of which a salt and hash would be stored in the database and then the user confirms his account by inputting the code they recieve via SMS.

Comment: Thanks Ruby, I was mainly just exploring the possibility that something like this already exists.  If not I can roll up my sleeves and start trying to work through it.   Tim, appreciate the link - some good info in that thread and I will start digging into it in the morning! :D