# How can I use Fabric's Digits with Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, twitter-fabric

I really love the [Twitter's Fabric SDK's Digit](https://docs.fabric.io/web/digits/getting-started.html). I recently saw that it can be even implemented for web. 
Wondering how it can be integrated with Ruby on Rails. I googled and tried digging through the resources but didn't find any!

Appreciate help!

Comment: In case it helps: https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/verify-user.html#generating-oauth-echo-headers I am just starting investigating..

Comment: Anybody build any packages for this yet, or for integrating it with devise like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521712/phone-number-based-devise-authentication-for-mobile-apps ?